# block_given? always returns true in erb templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

In Rails 5.2.3, I need to render a partial which takes an optional block.

```
# users/_user.html.erb
...
<% if block_given? %>
  <%= yield %>
<% else %>
  <h1>Goodbye world</h1>
<% end %>
...
```

However `block_given?` returns true regardless of which version I choose to go with:

```
<%# Version 1 - block_given? returns true %>
<%= render partial: "users/_user" do %>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
<% end %>

<%# Version 2 - block_given? also returns true %>
<%= render partial: "users/_user" %>
```

What's going on here and why is this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because all Rails templates support `content_for :xyz`, which is triggered by `yield :xyz`, it means all templates are always wrapped in a block that is prepared to fetch this `content_for` data.

Because this pre-programmed block is always there in order to accommodate `content_for`, it means `block_given?` will always return true.

I think this may actually be a small oversight in the Rails view design. It would be nice if we'd have a separate method to detect if a partial was supplied a block.

One idea for workaround:

```
<% if (block = yield).empty? %>
  <h1>Goodbye world</h1>
<% else %>
  <%= block %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

While being clever and a generic solution, I'm not a fan of the `(block = yield).empty?` in that particular instance.

In my use case and this one, where the default content is so simple, I prefer this approach:

```rb
<%= yield.presence || content_tag(:h1, "Goodbye world") %>
```

Comment: Still relevant for Rails 7. Thanks